# Trying to build minimal linux image with Poky , getting python import error

Tags: python, linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to buil a minimal linux image using yocto, When I try to run command bitbake `core-image-minimal` I get an error

```
from collections import MutableMapping, KeysView, ValuesView, ItemsView, OrderedDict
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

I've read somewhere that `MutableMapping` is deprecated in `Python3`. I tried to point to `python2.7` instead, but I still have the same error

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

I'm using poky `zeus` branch, ubuntu 22.04

Comment: We need a bit more info like: your OS with its version, and the Yocto version used. You need to check if your OS is compatible with your current Yocto build configuration (see [here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/system-requirements.html#supported-linux-distributions) but it's for the last Yocto version).
You might need to run a docker like `crops/poky` to run your Bitbake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zeus` branch, your OS (Ubuntu 22.04) [is not in the list of the supported ones.](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.0.4/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#detailed-supported-distros)

Here I can see two options (I think there is more, but they are the most simple ones):

- Install a supported OS on your machine (or on another machine)
- Use docker

---

For docker, install it following the [official docs for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Then you can run docker container on your poky folder to execute bitbake commands:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /path/to/poky:/workdir crops/poky:ubuntu-18.04 --workdir=/workdir
```